# Trouble installing some libraries in python (oauth2client and gspread)

Tags: python, pip, libraries, lib

I'm using python 3.7 (environment created by anaconda) and trying to run python code that uses some google libraries but I don't really know how to install them.

From PyCharm IDE (Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Available Packages) I cannot find those packages to install.
And from terminal, running 'pip install --upgrade oauth2client' or 'pip3 install --upgrade oauth2client' doesn't seem to work either.

What I don't understand is: to install packages/libraries on python 3.x, should i only use pip3? But what if there is more than one python environment? On which one pip will install those libraries?

Comment: Does ```pip install``` give you an error or does it appear not to do anything?

Comment: it seens to run normally, but appers to install into another python environment... idk where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Anaconda, you should also have an Anaconda Prompt (py37) program that functions like the terminal. Typing `pip install --upgrade oauth2client` into Anaconda Prompt (py37) will install the upgrade into your current python environment. Alternatively, you can use `conda install` with more [options](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages) (including specifying which environment you want).

Comment: That made it, thanks. `conda install gspread` was not finding the channel to download the lib, I needed to `conda activate` first then i run `pip install --upgrade gspread`. After that i could check with `conda list`. The lib was there. Used the same to oauth2client