# I cannot install pandas-datareader on windows for anaconda jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

I cannot import pandas_datareader on my jupyter notebook(via anaconda, python3) on my windows 10 laptop. It has been installed and I can see the file but It's having errors with importing into the jupyter notebook file. Any help?

I have tried :
pip install pandas-datareader ,
pip3 install pandas-datareader  ,
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader

I expect the the code to run smoothly however I get

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import pandas_datareader

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Comment: My first guess is that you're installing the package in a different `env` and running jupyter notebook in a different one. Can you check the top right corner of your jupyter notebook to see `Python [env_name]`. `env_name` would be the  env jupyter is running on. Go to anaconda prompt and `source activate env_name`. After which, you can try installing the package and running jupyter again.

Answer (score 2):

Most obvious reason can be that you are using differnt enviroments(kernels) for jupyter notebook and others. Try running this code inside jupyter notebook empty project:

```
try:
    from pip._internal.operations import freeze
except ImportError:  # if your pip version is bigger then 10
    from pip.operations import freeze

requirements = freeze.freeze()
for i in requirements:
    print(i)
```

and check if there are your's missing imports

Answer (score 0):

You have to run CMD Prompt from Anaconda navigator or find it from Start menu. Then use this command:

```
conda install pandas_datareader
```

I underwent similar difficulties and successfully fixed thanks to this post - [Trouble installing some libraries in python (oauth2client and gspread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808385/trouble-installing-some-libraries-in-python-oauth2client-and-gspread) Conda is installing packagies to environment for Anaconda which is obviously different than pip uses.